# Setting checkbox to 'checked' makes GET variable not being sent

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, get

I'm trying to make checkbox work like radiobutton with on/off value being passed to $info.
This code works fine, variable **info** is sent and read through GET

```
<?php if (empty($info)) { $info='on'; } ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="<?php if ($info=='on'){ echo "off"; } else {     echo "on"; } ?>" onchange="this.form.submit()"  />
```

adding this :

```
**<?php if (!empty($info)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>** 

<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="<?php if ($info=='on'){ echo "off"; } else {   echo "on"; } ?>" <?php if (!empty($info)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> onchange="this.form.submit()"  />
```

breaks something - GET variables are not sent or read, value is always OFF. Why ? It makes not sense.Adding **checked="checked"** to checkbox makes GET variables for this checkbox not being sent.

Comment: do you have setted `$info = $_GET['info'];`? and have you tryed  var dumping _GET? `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Why is the `value` dependent on whether the box is checked? The value should be the same regardless.

Comment: I'm a bit lost about what results you are actually getting… but a checkbox will only submit a value if it is checked, so it almost never makes sense to dynamically set its value because on if it was checked previously or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a checkbox is NOT checked, the value will not be submitted. So when you uncheck it, the onchange will trigger but nothing gets submitted because the box is not checked. Here is a solution:

```
<?php
$sub = $_POST['submitted'];
$info = $_POST['info'];
if ($sub) {
    if ($info == 'on') {
        echo 'turning it on!';
    } else {
        echo 'turning it OFF!';
    }
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="on" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?php echo $info == 'on' ? 'checked="checked" ' : ''; ?> />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
</form>
```